# ie8 Sortable not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a pretty complex setup of nested sortables

I have created a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mwagner72/Phbzc/

The problem is when using ie8, click the rearrange button, then use the blue box as drag handles. as you can see it is not working.  Works fine in other browsers.

I see a realated ticket ( I believe it is related) on the jquery site here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5197

But I am not understanding how to implement any of the fixes that are refered to in that bug ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Internet Explorer 8 takes control when attempting to drag `A` or `IMG` elements, preventing sortable from acting.

In your example removing the `A` and changing the drag handle to just a `SPAN` may work.